# Random Boolean array with 10 elements where 3 out of 10 are True

Tags: c#, arrays, list, random, boolean

I have been searching all over the forum and google but I think I am using the wrong key words or I do not understand the solution. What I am looking for is to create a list or array with 10 random Boolean elements where I can decide that 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 etc. elements are True. The order must be random, in the end I want a result like this e.g. (a 0.3 chance):

```
False
True
False
False
True
False
False
False
True
False
```

Thnx.

Comment: You can use the code below. I have not run it but should work. Please import System.Random.

    boolean[] randomBooleanArray(int len) {
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[len];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = rand.NextDouble() > 0.5;
        }
        return arr;
    }

Comment: @Egalitarian this does not ensure that `true` appears only three times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not create them in a know order (true, true, true, false, ....) and then use a good algorithm to shuffle them?

An option is the good old [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: The ask is different.

Comment: @Egalitarian How is the question different from what I suggest? The result is exactly what the OP asks: a randomised list with N `true` values. I just suggest taking two steps in creating it.